# Bash how to printf UTF-8

Tags: bash, debian, linux-mint, utf-8

Here is a small script to reproduce the default:

```
printf "|%-32s|\n" "Here, winter and there, summer"
printf "|%-32s|\n" "Ici, l'hiver et la, l'ete"
printf "|%-32s|\n" "Ici, l'hiver et là, l'été"
```

Result:

```
|Here, winter and there, summer  |
|Ici, l'hiver et la, l'ete       |
|Ici, l'hiver et là, l'été    |
```

System info:

```
LC_NAME  ==> fr_FR.UTF-8
uname -a ==> Linux hpms 4.15.0-163-generic #171-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 11:55:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**How can I configure the console or bash to handle correctly the accents in string length evaluation?**

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1599024/1686

Comment: Quick answer: `printf` deal with *bytes* not characters, but since  ${#var} give the length in characters, it's possible to manually pad the strings.